# git config completions messed up for fish shell on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: git, fish, ubuntu-20.04

I erased my hard drive and installed Ubuntu 20.04.1. Used `apt` to install fish version 3.1.0 and git 2.25.1. Tab completion shows errors whenever I use it with the `git config` command. The completion still works but it looks very ugly. How can I fix or debug this?

Example:

```
boz@mybox ~/myproject (develop|!35…)> 
git config --global credential.helper  /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecr__fish_is_first_arg: command not found
fish: 
__fish_git_using_command config; and __fish_is_first_arg
                                     ^
in command substitution
et/__fish_is_first_arg: command not found
fish: 
__fish_git_using_command config; and __fish_is_first_arg
                                     ^
boz@mybox ~/myproject (develop|!35…)> 
git config --global credential.helper  /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/
…ibsecret/git-credential-libsecret    …ibsecret/git-credential-libsecret.o
…ibsecret/git-credential-libsecret.c  …ibsecret/Makefile
```

Completes to ...

```
git config --global credential.helper  /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret
```

... which is correct. So, the completions work but are ugly.

So far I've only seen this with the `git config` command.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is a bug that is fixed in fish 3.1.2 but it's not available in apt yet.
See: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/7176#issuecomment-653744454